# not able to establish foreign key constrain in mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I am not able to establish foreign key constrain in mysql.
Mysql version: 5.0

Queries I have used are:

```
create table department (
 deptid varchar(10),
 primary key (deptid),
 name varchar(20)
);


create table employee (
  empid varchar(10),
  primary key (empid),
  name varchar(20),
  age int,
  deptid varchar(10),
  foreign key (deptid) references department (deptid)
);
```

I am still able to add employee with department id which is not present in department table.

Thanks.

EDIT: I changed engine for my tables but still this constraint is not working. I changed engine by using following query: alter table department engine=InnoDB;

Comment: Check if your table is using Innodb or Myisam. Myisam doesn't support foreign key constraints.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, apparently not.. I just tried it!

Comment: @mmarinero, yes, it's using MyISAM.

Comment: I changed engine for my tables but still this constraint is not working. I changed engine by using following query: alter table department engine=InnoDB;

Comment: Try adding the constraint again with alter table or recreate the table specifying the engine, the constraint was probably dropped when the table was created.

Comment: @mmarinero, creating table again worked, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mmarinero suggested that foreign key constraint doesn't work for MyISAM engine. I checked engine for my tables using following query:

> show table status;

It showed MyISAM engine for my tables.

I dropped my tables and recreated them using following queries:

> create table department (deptid varchar(10), primary key (deptid), name varchar(20)) engine=InnoDB;
>
> create table employee (empid varchar(10), primary key (empid), name varchar(20), age int, deptid varchar(10), foreign key (deptid) references department (deptid)) engine=InnoDB;

Now my foreign constraint is working.

Thanks mmarinero.